# How to use the Broadcast Receiver in android to vibrate the device ?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-vibration

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    public void onReceive(Context context , Intent intent){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Your time is up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Vibrator vibrator; 
        // ERROR here (vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(2000);
    }
}
```

While using the Broadcast Receiver to vibrate the device when using an Alarm, there's an error as shown above . What may be the possible reason for an error here ?

Comment: What's the error? Maybe you forgot to add the permission in the manifest. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>

Comment: Its a syntax error that a ';' is missing but it isn't. and regarding the permission, yes i have added that.

Comment: @iamthe.exception your question made me solve this issue: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939164/change-output-volume-in-broadcastreceiver-for-notification-for-non-streaming-pre)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Vibrator v;
v=(Vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(3000);
```

Comment: This looks better - the vibrator variable wasn't being initialised. I'd have thought you'd be getting a NullPointerException...

Answer (score 0):

did you give permission?

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
```